# How can I cache background images using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, image, caching

When changing background images, those images won't cache even when using apache mod_expires module.

Changing apache's mod_expires module, looping thru all the images in a separate div that is hidden somewhere 1x1px behind the z-index.

Here is how I managed to cache the images and they WON'T get reloaded till the browser window is closed.
It loops thru all the images creating an HTML image node that is stored inside a cache array. Javascript's garbage collector won't remove the images from the cache once they're looped.

```
const images = ["/img/1.jpg","/img/2.jpg","/img/1.jpg"];
const cache = Array();
for(const path of images){
  const img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.src = path;
  cache.push(img);
}
```

Is it possible to cache the images persistent inside the browser's cache?

Comment: Maybe you can use cookie for that. Also you may use some .htaccess tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if all HTTP headers are set correctly by the server. In Firefox and Chromium you can do this by pressing F12 and then switch to the network tab.

But as far as I know the cache headers just say whether the file *can* be cached. At the end it's up to the browser if it wants to cache the file. If the browser does not want to cache the file I personally would not try to find a workaround.

But one workaround would be to save the image in the *localStorage* javascript object. On my system *localStorage* is limited to 5MB per web page.

Comment: I've tried the Cache-control meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">` and I've also used an image node (not background image) and the cache isn't working.